# Searching for key in ConvertFrom-StringData hash

Tags: powershell, hash

I have a hash table that I got from a file, command used:

```
[array]$hash= Get-Content -raw '../../file.txt' | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

file.txt looks like this:

```
key=value
```

It works perfectly, the problem is when I trying to search using `$hash.GetEnumerator`.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$hash.GetEnumerator() | where {$_.value -match 'value'}  // or with key
```

It always returns an empty value. Got it from [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.windows.powershell/cApKMX9rKVY), tried to create a local hash using `$hash=@{}` then `add`, and it worked(like for the guy from the link).

Note! `$hash.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name` works for me too, and returning the right table.

Do you have any idea how can I search(-eq or -match) in the hash table that I have created?

Comment: Do you want to find exact matches or partial matches? Do you want to find the values by key or by (partial) value?

Comment: I want to find key's value, and then send it to function as value.
For example:
`function ($hash.GetEnumerator() | where {$_.key -match 'something'})`
Or with another variable, doesn't matter. The problem is the search

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$hash.GetEnumerator() | where {$($_.Value) -match 'value'}
```

or like this

```
$hash.Keys  | % {$($hash[$_]) -eq 'value'} | %{$hash[$_]}
```

or better, you can transform your hashtable into objects list

```
$hash.GetEnumerator()  | 
    % {New-Object psobject -Property @{Name=$($_.Name); Value=$($_.Value)} } | 
         where Value -match 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response to my comment asking for clarification didn't clarify too much, but I'm going to assume that you want to find the value for a particular key in the hashtable. That kind of lookup is the core functionality of [hashtables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx).

```
$ht = @'
foo=23
bar=42
baz=5
'@ | ConvertFrom-StringData

$key = 'bar'
$ht[$key]  # returns 42
```

If you actually want a fuzzy match on the keys you could replace the direct lookup with a [wildcard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088.aspx) match like this:

```
$partialKey = 'ba*'
$ht.Keys | Where-Object {
  $_ -like $partialKey
} | ForEach-Object {
  $ht[$_]  # returns 42 and 5
}
```

or a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) match like this:

```
$partialKey = '^ba'
$ht.Keys | Where-Object {
  $_ -match $partialKey
} | ForEach-Object {
  $ht[$_]  # returns 42 and 5
}
```

As an alternative to looking up multiple keys in a loop you could also build a list of keys and use that list in a single lookup:

```
$partialKey = 'ba*'
$keys = $ht.Keys | Where-Object { $_ -like $partialKey }
$ht[$keys]  # returns 42 and 5
```